# How do I update a model in a ReliableDictionary?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Consider this mock scenario where I have the following class:

```
public class Person {
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

I currently have a ReliableDictionary(Guid,Person).  I'd like to change my Person model by splitting out the Address, to the following:

```
public class Person {
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Address {
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Street {get;set;}
  ...
}
```

I would then have two ReliableDictionaries, one for persons and one for addresses.

What is the proper way to split these entities and migrate the data during an upgrade?  I feel like there used to be documentation on this, but I can no longer find it.

Thanks!

Comment: this is an important article to read: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important requirement is that your model needs to be backward compatible. A stored model should be able to load, no matter the changes to your model.

Converting all stored models requires you to loop through the stored models, make changes and store them again. You need to write specific code for this. This could be included in the microservice, or you could create a temporary microservice which calls the microservice which holds the data. After the conversion is done you can remove the code or the microservice.

You could also do this 'on the fly'. Whenever a model is loaded during production you check the version number (you need to specify a version field on your model). If the version is below a certain value, convert it.